signup button aint working with my firebase
i made a signup page where u put infos and it saves in database , im using firebase in this
this is my HTML code for the button :
<!-- Signup Popup -->
    <div class="popup" id="signup-popup">
        <div class="popup__content">
            <h2>Signup</h2>
            <form>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
                <button type="submit" class="button" id="signup">Signup</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

and this is the firebase :
// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

//inputs
const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
const password = document.getElementById('password').value;

//submit button
const submit = document.getElementById('signup');
submit.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
  alert(5)
})

i tried to change the id in const submit = document.getElementById('signup') to signup-popup

you are getting the email and password by ID in firebase but you didn't specify those in your HTML. Consider accepting the below answer if it fixed your issue

you can add an id to the form and get the form.
add ids to the email and user name
 <form id="signup-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username" required>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" required>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" required>
            <button type="button" class="button" id="signup">Signup</button>
        </form>

now get a reffernce to the form and add event listener for the submit button.
then use the firebase auth to signin the user
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = firebase.auth();

const signupForm = document.getElementById('signup-form');

signupForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  const password = document.getElementById('password').value;

  auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      console.log('User signed up:', userCredential.user);
      signupForm.reset();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error.message);
    });
});


It is also good to change the button type to <button type="button" instead of <button type="submit"=> I've seen some case where the form is submitted before the call to the Firebase method could be triggered

you are definitely right, edited the code. thanks
